# Django Ajax response from model

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Здравствуйте. Хочу узнать ответ на свой вопрос есть view которое отвечает за прием от ajax данных введенных в форму комментариев. Как сделать добавление комментариев на страницу без ее перезагрузки. Не очень силен в ajax и jquery поэтому очень прошу помочь примерами с кодом. Благодарю заранее за помощь

```
views.py
def comment_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        c = Comments(name=request.POST.get('name', '')[:50],
                 email=request.POST.get('email', '')[:150],
                 web_site=request.POST.get('web_site', '')[:150],
                 comment=request.POST.get('comment', ''),
                 blog_id=request.POST.get('blog', '')
                 )
        c.save()

        return HttpResponse('ok')
   else:
        return HttpResponse('bad')



sendform.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#submit').click(function () {
    //
    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    var email = $('input[name=email]');
    var web_site = $('input[name=web_site]');
    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
    var blog = $('p#pk').data('item');
    var reply = $('p#reply').data('item');
    //
    var error = '';
    //Проверка введена ли информация в поля формы
    if ((name.val() == '') || (email.val() == '')) {
        error = 'Вы не ввели имя и e-mail';
        if (name.val() == '' && email.val() != '') {
            error = 'Вы не ввели имя'
        }
        if (name.val() != '' && email.val() == '') {
            error = 'Вы не ввели e-mail'
        }
        alert(error)
    };
    if ((comment.val() == '')){
        error = 'Вы не ввели комментарий'
        alert(error)
    };
    //if ((blog.val() != '')){
        //error = 'Pk не отправлено'
       // alert(blog.val())
    //}
// Если поля заполнены, отправляем их значения
    if (!error) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/add_comment/',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: {'name': name.val(), 'email': email.val(), 'web_site':     web_site.val(), 'comment': comment.val(), 'blog': blog},
            error: function () {
                alert('Ошибка получения запроса')
            },
            success: function (data) {
               **ЧТО ПИСАТЬ ЗДЕСЬ ЧТОБЫ ПОСЛЕ ОТПРАВКИ ФОРМЫ 
               ДАННЫЕ КОТОРЫЕ БЫЛИ ВВЕДЕНЫ В ФОРМУ КОМЕНТАРИЕВ
               БЕЗ ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ СТРАНИЦЫ ОТОБРАЗИЛИСЬ В ДОБАВЛЕННЫХ
               КОММЕНТАРИЯХ**




            }



        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Придётся таки разобраться в ajax и jquery, если вы хотите их использовать

В приведённом примере вам лучше использовать jquery метод [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) к тому контейнеру, где у вас комментарии. В переменной data у вас будет лежать данные, полученные от сервера, их надо засунуть в какой-то шаблон.

Если совсем банально, то как-то так

```
$('#comments-container').append('<p>' + data.name + '<br>' + data.comment + '</p>')
```

### Как в этом случае я бы организовал Backend

Вообще для работы со всеми асинхронными инструментами лучше придерживаться правил [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Если вкратце - при создании объекта (методом POST) вы должны вернуть на сервере либо 201 created, либо 400 с ошибками в json. При создании объекта возвращается только что созданный объект в том же json, а не **ok** и прочие строки, как любят делать очень многие, не сведущие в этой теме.

Если объект необходимо обновить, то для этого используются методы PUT или PATCH (разница есть). Для удаления объекта используется  HTTP метод DELETE.

Api лучше разделять на 2 типа - список объектов и страница детального просмотра. Соответственно список может быть чего угодно, например, комментариев. Например, по ссылке /api/comments/. Детальный просмотр комментария с id 1 может быть организован по ссылке /api/comments/1/. Соответственно исходя из этого примеры использования:

- Чтобы создать комментарий отправляем POST на /api/comments/. В ответе получаем, например

  {
      'id': 1,
      'text': 'hello world',
      'owner': 10
  }
- Чтобы отредактировать комментарий отправляем PUT запрос на /api/comments/1/. В ответе **снова получаем полный объект**, как в примере выше. Таким образом вы сможете, например, обновить свой комментарий на странице

Ну этого для начала хватит.

Теперь следующий вопрос - как это всё сделать, да ещё и чтобы не заморачиваться?

Решение есть, за вас всё уже давно написано. Могу посоветовать [Django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). У него есть хорошое браузерное api, так что вы сможете поупражняться во всём вышеизложенном не написав ни строчки js.

По поводу того как получить объекты комментариев для определённого поста - у rest framework есть фильтры. Соответственно после их объявления (читайте [доки](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)) вы сможете делать запросы примерно такого вида `/api/comments/?post=25` где 25 - id поста и получать все комментарии для него. Ещё в нём есть пагинация, которая прикручивается с полпинка, так что вы сможете ещё и сделать бесконечный скролл, например. Но это уже по желанию

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я как раз и занимаюсь изучением jquery и ajax в данный момент. Я пробовал методом alert(data.name) но после отправки формы выводилось диалоговое окно со значением undefined. Могли бы ли вы пояснить почему alert к примеру возвращает мне неопределенное значение undefined?

Comment: Вероятнее всего потому что вы возвращаете HttpResponse jquery не может вытянуть оттуда никаких данных - он то ожидает json, а вы ему строку кидаете. Попробуйте вместо этого JsonResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: Ну если допустить что я верну JsonResponse. Эта вьюха отвечает за принятие комментариев и сохранение их в базу. А сами комментарии отдаются другой вьюхой, потому что я связал комментарии к посту по pk модели. Если этого не сделать то куча комментов со всех постов будут везде это логично. А как вы думаете если сделать еще один запрос ajax из другой вьюхи которая отдает комменты? просто что писать в url ajax не совсем понятно так как там идет ссылка на id модели. Типа blog/1- первый пост, blog/2 - второй и т.д

Comment: Или же если я верну JsonResponse из той же вьюхи которая сохраняет комменты в базу у меня получится вернуть именно те комменты которые относятся к определенному посту?

Comment: Вообще вам не стоит изобретать велосипед. Давайте я дополню ответ так, как сделал бы я

Comment: Спасибо за помощь буду копать в сторону RestFull. Ответ не могу принять решенным пока что. Очень благодарен еще раз. Как разберусь с Rest сразу поставлю галку. Думаю это для вас что то значит...

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста